# Solr shingles matching

Tags: solr

I'm currently working on autcomplete widget. I'd like to use it also for selecting facets on the page. One of my DB facet tables looks like this:

```
id | name
1  | Lace
2  | Super Fine
3  | Fine
4  | Light
5  | Medium
6  | Bulky
7  | Super bulky
```

Here are some examples what I'd expect, left column is the text that user provides, right column is what Solr result should be:

```
1) word1...wordn super             => Super Fine, Super Bulky
2) super word1...wordn             => --- (nothing should be found)
3) word1 super fine                => Super Fine
4) word1 super fine word2...wordn  => Super Fine
5) word1...wordn super fine        => Super Fine
6) word1 super word2...wordn fine  => Fine
```

So I'm almost there, but the case 6) isn't working for me, ie. Solr finds Super Fine instead of Fine.

This is what I see in admin -> schema browser -> **Top Terms**:

```
2  |  super
   |  bulky
   |  fine
1  |  super bulky
   |  medium
   |  super fine
   |  light
   |  lace
```

**query parameters:**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=word1+super+word2+fine&fl=group_name&df=group_name&wt=xml&indent=true&debugQuery=true&defType=edismax&qf=group_name&mm=2&pf=group_name&ps=1&qs=1&pf2=group_name&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true
```

**query debug log:**

```
  <str name="rawquerystring">word1 super word2 fine</str>
  <str name="querystring">word1 super word2 fine</str>
  <str name="parsedquery">(+((DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:word1)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:super)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:word2)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:fine)))~2) DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:"word1 super word2 fine"~1)) (DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:"word1 super"~1)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:"super word2"~1)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((group_name:"word2 fine"~1))))/no_coord</str>
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">+(((group_name:word1) (group_name:super) (group_name:word2) (group_name:fine))~2) (group_name:"word1 super word2 fine"~1) ((group_name:"word1 super"~1) (group_name:"super word2"~1) (group_name:"word2 fine"~1))</str>
  <lst name="explain">
    <str name="portal.group.2">
0.29696858 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0.29696858 = (MATCH) product of:
    0.59393716 = (MATCH) sum of:
      0.29696858 = (MATCH) weight(group_name:super in 1) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
        0.29696858 = score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
          0.15038839 = queryWeight, product of:
            3.1594841 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=26)
            0.047599033 = queryNorm
          1.9746776 = fieldWeight in 1, product of:
            1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
              1.0 = termFreq=1.0
            3.1594841 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=26)
            0.625 = fieldNorm(doc=1)
      0.29696858 = (MATCH) weight(group_name:fine in 1) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
        0.29696858 = score(doc=1,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
          0.15038839 = queryWeight, product of:
            3.1594841 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=26)
            0.047599033 = queryNorm
          1.9746776 = fieldWeight in 1, product of:
            1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
              1.0 = termFreq=1.0
            3.1594841 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=26)
            0.625 = fieldNorm(doc=1)
    0.5 = coord(2/4)
</str>
```

and my **schema.xml** excerpt:

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2"
         outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" tokenSeparator=" "/>

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help with this, as I just started working with Solr and I think I don't fully understand all of the concepts yet (perhaps it's not possible to do what I wish to in Solr ?).